# Global module MODULE_NOT_FOUND if started from pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have the [emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs) package installed globally. My `NODE_PATH` is correctly showing the value from `npm -g root`: /usr/lib/node_modules. In Node REPL, the following runs from any folder without error:

```
var email = require("emailjs/email");
```

However, in a Node script started via `pm2`, `var email = require("emailjs/email")` is resulting in `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`:

> Error: Cannot find module 'emailjs/email'

What could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the environment for `pm2` is frozen at what it was when it was first run. My very first app didn't have the `NODE_PATH` parameter set. It was set only later. So, even though the environment has the `NODE_PATH` parameter set, `pm2` doesn't see it.

Therefore, there is a need to start the new app with the `--update-env` option.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (like this) it depends from PM2. Try this:

```
sudo pm2 update
```

Comment: So now require like this: var email = require('emailjs');